# neglect it--------------Sending an array to servlet from jsp page and recieving it in servlet------------ neglect it

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets

*

> neglect it

*

I am lerner in JSP and java field. I am stuck in a problem. I hv mentioned my code below.

My JSP code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org      /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#save").click( function ()
{


var arrayxx= new Array(5);
arrayxx[0]=0;
arrayxx[1]=3;
arrayxx[2]=4;
arrayxx[3]=9;





 $.get('Save1',{arrayX:arrayxx},function(responseJson) 
    {


} );



});
});







</script>
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="save" value="save" ></input>

</body>
</html>
```

My servlet:

```
 import java.io.IOException;



    import javax.servlet.ServletException;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



    public class Save1 extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


 public Save1() {
     super();

 }


 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("INSIDE SERVLET");
    String [] yourList =  request.getParameterValues("arrayX");
    System.out.println(request.toString());
        System.out.println(yourList[0]);

}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)          throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

 }
```

I cant able to pass the array from JSP to servlrt.
Please help me with this. When i receive the array, i found that array does not contain any element.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank u for answering .. there ws mistake in the way i ws handling the servlet .. sorry for the trouble.. i could solve it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement I would suggest you to go for ajax like this way

```
$.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "servlet", //Your full URL goes here
                    data: { parametername: parametervalue},
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        //alert(data); 

}
```

Comment: i am very new to all these .. can u give me small example plz

Comment: still i am facing d same problem

Comment: @user2814799 What will I understand if you simply say *still i am facing d same problem * tell me the exact problem

Comment: @user2814799 you are welcome and do not edit the question the way you are editing now(neglect it...) Questions in stackoverflow are meant for future users also

Comment: i tot it was not useful .. so .. i edited it like that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43257/discussion-between-user2814799-and-jquerylearner)